# Looping through fishnet feature in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, features, for-loop

I would like to loop through a fishnet feature and add the extent of the cells to the attribute table.

Here is the relevant code part:

```
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fishnet_feature)
for row in cur:
    ext = arcpy.Describe(row).extent
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = ext.XMin, ext.XMax, ext.YMin, ext.YMax
    row.setValue("LEFT", y_min)
    row.setValue("TOP", x_max)
    row.setValue("RIGHT", y_max)
    row.setValue("BOTTOM", x_min)
    cur.updateRow(k)

del cur, row
```

I got error message

> RuntimeError: Object: Describe input value is not valid type

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well, for starters, you didn't use a DA cursor. Second was using `Describe` on a row (which is what the error said). Use a DA cursor with `"shape@"` and the other field names, then extract the extent from the `Geometry`. Also `k` is not defined.

Comment: You’ve presented a copy/paste from your code instead of a code snippet that works up to where you’re stuck. I recommend always using `arcpy.da` cursors rather than the old style.

Comment: I am trying to fix it. I will text the result

Comment: Hint: Do ***not*** use `Describe` -- `Geometry` has an `extent` property

Comment: As much as I love Python and use ArcPy cursors quite a lot, there is an ArcGIS Pro geoprocessing tool that can add extent information as new attributes to a data set:  [Add Geometry Attributes (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm)

Comment: You've also got some odd mappings from extent to column -- LEFT should be XMin,  RIGHT XMax, TOP YMax, and BOTTOM YMin.

Answer (score 2):

The first rule of ArcPy cursors is "Only use DA Cursors."  But your real issue is
the incorrect use of `arcpy.Describe` on a `arcpy.UpdateCursor` row (which is what the error indicates).

There are other issues:

- You can generally stop the code snippet at the line with the error
- You're mapping the corner dimensions incorrectly (e.g. `LEFT` :: `extent.XMin` not `extent.YMin`)
- The `updateRow` is on an undefined variable (`k`)
- It would be faster to calculate values using [AddGeometryAttributes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm) with the "EXTENT" properties (though you would then get the standard fields)

The result, using a DA cursor, would be:

```py
ucols = ['shape@','LEFT','TOP','RIGHT','BOTTOM']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fishnet_feature,ucols) as cursor:
    for row in cur:
        ext = row[0].extent
        cursor.updateRow([row[0],ext.XMin,ext.YMax,ext.XMax,ext.YMin])
```